# How to call/manipulate a deconstructed object when it's a function's parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm going through the lessons on freecodecamp for Javascript. In the ES6 tutorials there's: ["use destructuring assignment to pass an object as a function's parameter"](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-destructuring-assignment-to-pass-an-object-as-a-functions-parameters)

While I understand how they converted it to this, I don't understand at all what the purpose is or how to call/use the values/whatever inside this function. I tried searching online, but couldn't find anything related to functions with deconstructed objects as their parameters. Basically I don't understand how I can call or manipulate, or what I'm to do with an object in this form

i.e.

```
let dog1 = {
    name : "whitey",
    colour: "white"
}

let dog2 = {
    name : "blackey",
    colour: "black"
}

//const {name,colour} = dog1 
//let's me call each property like: console.log(name)="whitey"

var dogfunc = (dog1) =>{
   const {name, colour} = dog1}

//which can be rewritten as:     
var dogfunc = ({name, colour}) => {}     

//Now I'm stuck, I don't understand how I would call each property of dog1 or dog2
//I thought the point would be to allow me call/edit either dog1 or dog2 properties.
```

Comment: Don't you mean a function's arguments, not properties?  There's a giant difference and it could help your Google research

Comment: I wrote wrote properties by mistake, I meant parameters, fixed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring -- you don't use `dog1.name`, etc., inside the function, you simply use `name` and `colour`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of destructuring assignment is to reduce the extra necessary code as well as to "only get what is needed".

Using your example, consider a function which receives a dog object and print its name:

```js
const dogObject = { 
  name: "Doge",
  breed: "Labrador"
}

function printDogName(dog){
  console.log(dog.name);
}

// or using destructuring
function printDogNameWithInternalDestructuring(dog){
  const { name } = dog;
  console.log(name);
}

printDogName(dogObject); // Doge
printDogNameWithInternalDestructuring(dogObject); // Doge
```

If you read carefully, you can see that from the whole dog object (it can contain a lot of other properties), we are only interested in the `name`. So, in the body of our functions we needed to get this property from the received object.

Using destructuring assignment, we can move the destructuring to the function required arguments definition. The function definition specifies which kind of object we expect as argument and from this object which properties are required, in our case, the name.

```js
function printDogNameWithDestructuring({name}){
  console.log(name);
};

printDogNameWithDestructuring(dogObject); // Doge
```

From your example:

```js
let dog1 = {
    name : "whitey",
    colour: "white"
}

let dog2 = {
    name : "blackey",
    colour: "black"
}

const {name,colour} = dog1 
//let's me call each property like: console.log(name)="whitey"
console.log(name) // prints whitney

var dogfunc = (dog1) => {
  const {name, colour} = dog1
  console.log(name);
}

dogfunc(dog1); // prints whitney
dogfunc(dog2); // prints blackey

//which can be rewritten as:  
var dogfunc = ({name, colour}) => {
  console.log(name)
}

// or using a shorter syntax   
var dogfunc = ({name, colour}) => console.log(name);

dogfunc(dog1); // prints whitney
dogfunc(dog2); // prints blackey
```

Comment: var dogfunc = ({name})=>{dogfunc.name="new name"}; dogfunc(dog1); console.log(dog1.names); doesn't do anything. what am I supposed to be doing to change things via the function like the name?

Comment: These are two different aspects. Destructuring Assignment "removes some extra lines and makes our code look neat. This has the added benefit of not having to manipulate an entire object in a function - only the fields that are needed are copied inside the function" [Source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-destructuring-assignment-to-pass-an-object-as-a-functions-parameters). It is not used to modify (mutate) an object, like changing the name.